# Get record type labels as a list of strings

Tags: f#

Is it possible to get the labels of a record type as a list of strings? 
For example, given the following type:

```
type Person = {
    Name: string
    Age: int
}
```

I want a function that gives me `["Name"; "Age";]`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There are some cases when it's useful, but it is much more rare than in many other languages. Maybe there's a better solution to the problem that motivated you to ask... :-)

Comment: you could serialize into JSON, and then get the properties, either by parsing the text or by using the JSOn type provider. Your other option is reflection, as mentioned below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.GetRecordFields` to get the property info for a record type, from which you can get the field names.

```
 let props = FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.GetRecordFields(typeof<Person>)
 let names = props |> Array.map(fun prop -> prop.Name)
 printfn "%A" names
```

Output:

```
[|"Name"; "Age"|]
```